# Defining indices independently for same field in child and parent documents in different collections

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I have two classes that look like this:

```
@Document(collection = 'rule')
class Rule {
    @Indexed(unique = true)
    String name
}

@Document(collection = 'archived_rule')
class ArchivedRule extends Rule {
    @Indexed(unique = false)
    String name
}
```

Rules are the primary domain class that my application works with. Only the latest version of each Rule is stored in the 'rule' collection. When a Rule is updated, a copy of it is made and is saved in the 'archived_rule' collection.

The name field should be unique in the 'rule' collection. It should be able to have duplicates in the 'archived_rule' collection.

Defining my classes as I have above does not seem to work. When I start my application, I get an exception like this:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.model.MappingException: Ambiguous field mapping detected! Both @org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.Indexed(expireAfterSeconds=-1, dropDups=false, sparse=false, useGeneratedName=false, background=false, unique=true, name=, collection=, direction=ASCENDING) private java.lang.String ...Rule.name and @org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.Indexed(expireAfterSeconds=-1, dropDups=false, sparse=false, useGeneratedName=false, background=false, unique=false, name=, collection=, direction=ASCENDING) private java.lang.String ...ArchivedRule.name map to the same field name name! Disambiguate using @Field annotation!
```

I have also tried not specifying the name field at all in the ArchivedRule class, but in that case it creates a unique index on the 'name' field in the 'archived_rule' collection.

I have thought that I could make Rule and ArchivedRule unrelated by inheritance and then explicitly re-define all the fields I need to save from Rule in ArchivedRule. I would like to avoid having to do that, though.

Is there some other way that I can specify my classes so that Rule.name has a unique index and ArchivedRule.name does not have a unique index?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by adding an abstract base class with the shared fields other than name that both Rule and ArchivedRule extend from. They each then define their own version of name with the appropriate index configuration.

```
class RuleBase {
    String sharedField
}

@Document(collection = 'rule')
class Rule extends RuleBase {
    @Indexed(unique = true)
    String name
}

@Document(collection = 'archived_rule')
class ArchivedRule extends RuleBase {
    @Indexed(unique = false)
    String name
}
```